# Auto-complete a tuple

Tags: java, autocomplete, smartgwt

I have a database table like this

```
Port Code     | Country   |Port_Name
--------------------------------------
 1234         | Australia | port1
 2345         | India     | Mumbai
 2341         | Australia | port2
 ...
```

The table consists of around 12000 entries.I need to auto-complete as the user enter's the query.Now the query can be any either a port-code,country or a port name.For example if the users partial query is '12' and the drop-down should display `1234 | Australia | port1`.The problem that i'm facing now is that for each user entry i'm querying the database which makes the auto-complete really slow.So is there a way to optimize this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in smartgwt use comboboxitem.Then override getPickListFilterCriteria of comboxitem like this

```
ComboBoxItem portSelect = new ComboBoxItem("PORT_ATTRIB", "") {

      @Override
      public Criteria getPickListFilterCriteria() {
        if (getValue() != null && getValue() instanceof String) {
          criteria = new AdvancedCriteria(OperatorId.AND, new Criterion[]{new Criterion("portValue",
              OperatorId.EQUALS, getDisplayValue())});
        }
        return criteria;
      }
    };
```

Every key press will give you a criteria which u can pass to your query.Query will be something like`select * from port where portName like '+criteria+%' or portCode like '+criteria+%`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) and a RAMDirectory. You build an index on your data, and implement a data lookup service to check from time to time if changes in the database occured. Or any other update from your database for your Lucene Index. See [Lucene for Indexing your DB](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_can_I_use_Lucene_to_index_a_database.3F) and for Querying use the [MultiFieldQueryParser](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_can_I_search_over_multiple_fields.3F).

Answer (score 0):

Is your database indexed correctly? Lookups on indexed columns should be pretty fast - 12k rows is not a great deal for any relational DB.

Another thing I could suggest is to load the database table data, into an in memory table. I've done this in MySQL long time back : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html . This will help specially if the data does not change very frequently - so a one time load up of the data into a in memory table will be quick. After that, all queries should be executed on this in memory table and these are amazingly fast.